# Setting unknown property: yii\swiftmailer\Message::form

Tags: yii2

Помогите пожалуйста новичку. При регистрации появляется ошибка:

Неизвестное свойство - yii \ base \ UnknownPropertyException 
Установка неизвестного свойства: yii \ swiftmailer \ Message :: form

```
2. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 546 – yii\base\BaseObject::__set('form', ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'])

3. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php at line 107 – yii\BaseYii::configure(yii\swiftmailer\Message, ['form' => ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'], 'mailer' => yii\swiftmailer\Mailer])

4. yii\base\BaseObject::__construct(['form' => ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'], 'mailer' => yii\swiftmailer\Mailer])

5. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 383 – ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs([['form' => ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'], 'mailer' => yii\swiftmailer\Mailer]])

6. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 156 – yii\di\Container::build('yii\swiftmailer\Message', [], ['form' => ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'], 'mailer' => yii\swiftmailer\Mailer])

7. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php at line 349 – yii\di\Container::get('yii\swiftmailer\Message', [], ['form' => ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'], 'mailer' => yii\swiftmailer\Mailer])

8. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMailer.php at line 236 – yii\BaseYii::createObject(['form' => ['support@example.com' => 'Finance'], 'mailer' => yii\swiftmailer\Mailer])

9. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMailer.php at line 175 – yii\mail\BaseMailer::createMessage()

10. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\finance\services\auth\SignupService.php at line 28 – yii\mail\BaseMailer::compose(['html' => 'confirm-html', 'text' => 'confirm-text'], ['user' => finance\entities\User\User])

22                            );
23    $this->save($user);
24
25    $sent = $this->mailer
26        ->compose(
27            ['html' => 'confirm-html', 'text' => 'confirm-text'],
28            ['user' => $user]
29        )
30        ->setTo($form->email)
31        ->setSubject('Signup confirm for ' . \Yii::$app->name)
32        ->send();
33    if (!$sent) {
34        throw new \RuntimeException('Email sending error.');

11. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\frontend\controllers\auth\SignupController.php at line 46 – finance\services\auth\SignupService::signup(finance\forms\auth\SignupForm)

40                         */
41    public function actionRequest()
42    {
43        $form = new SignupForm();
44        if ($form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $form->validate()) {
45            try {
46                $this->service->signup($form);
47                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');
48                return $this->goHome();
49            } catch (\DomainException $e) {
50                Yii::$app->errorHandler->logException($e);
51                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
52            }

12. frontend\controllers\auth\SignupController::actionRequest()
13. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php at line 57 – call_user_func_array([frontend\controllers\auth\SignupController, 'actionRequest'], [])

51                            $args = $this->controller->bindActionParams($this, $params);
52        Yii::debug('Running action: ' . get_class($this->controller) . '::' . $this->actionMethod . '()', __METHOD__);
53        if (Yii::$app->requestedParams === null) {
54            Yii::$app->requestedParams = $args;
55        }
56 
57        return call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->actionMethod], $args);
58    }
59}

14. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php at line 157 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams([])

15. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php at line 528 – yii\base\Controller::runAction('request', [])
16. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php at line 103 – yii\base\Module::runAction('auth/signup/request', [])

17. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php at line 386 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
18. in C:\Users\acer\OpenServer\domains\finance\frontend\web\index.php at line 17 – yii\base\Application::run()

11                        require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php',
12    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php',
13    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main.php',
14    require __DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'
15);
16 
17(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Я исправила ошибку в PasswordResetRequestForm.php указала не полный путь: 'targetClass' => '\finance\entities\User\User', теперь при регистрации выходит другая ошибка:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'finance.users' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username`='admin3')
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 1146
    [2] => Table 'finance.users' doesn't exist
)
```

То есть базовая таблица не существует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер.
Если этот код находится в одной модели

```
$this->save($user);

$sent = $this->mailer
    ->compose(
        ['html' => 'confirm-html', 'text' => 'confirm-text'],
        ['user' => $user]
    )
    ->setTo($form->email)
    ->setSubject('Signup confirm for ' . \Yii::$app->name)
    ->send();
if (!$sent) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Email sending error.');
```

То я думаю, что надо заменить $form->email на $user->email

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75339/discussion-on-answer-by-slo-nik-setting-unknown-property-yii-swiftmailer-messag).